# Dependency error when using MobilePush SDK React Native module

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react-native

We are running into an issue with implementing the [react-native-marketingcloudsdk](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk) version 8.1.0 in our application specifically on Android. Refer to below screenshot.

We have tried a few different solutions from changing package versions to increasing our compileSDK version etc. We are running React Native version 0.68.7 and although [the ReadMe states](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) the module is compatible with any React Native version above 0.60 we are running into this build issue.

[image: MobilePush React Native Build Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, and also updading [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) build version alongside the compile and target SDKs to version 34 solved the issue.